# Xamarin.Android System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ReactiveUI.ControlFetcherMixin' threw an exception

Tags: xamarin.android, reactiveui

I am getting the following exception when trying to call WireUpControls() with Xamarin.Android + ReactiveUI.

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'ReactiveUI.ControlFetcherMixin' threw an exception

I've checked the following but I'm still getting the exception.

1. Naming conventions for the controls as defined in https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/xamarin-android/wire-up-controls
2. By changing the Resolving strategies.

I only have a ListView in the Layout.

**Main Activity:**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            this.WireUpControls(ControlFetcherMixin.ResolveStrategy.ExplicitOptIn);
            SetupUserInterface();

            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.OutletListing, x => x.OutletListItems).DisposeWith(SubscriptionDisposables);

        }
```

**Update:**
Found the inner exception

```
+       ex  {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ReactiveUI.ControlFetcherMixin' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: You're using multiple resource ID's with the same name but with different casings which isn't allowed for WireUpControls: { Image = image }, { Text = text }, { Text2 = text2 } ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: image
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].TryInsert (TKey key, TValue value, System.Collections.Generic.InsertionBehavior behavior) [0x000bb] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].Add (TKey key, TValue value) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] keySelector, System.Func`2[T,TResult] elementSelector, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[T] comparer) [0x0009e] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] keySelector, System.Func`2[T,TResult] elementSelector) [0x00000] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
  at ReactiveUI.ControlFetcherMixin..cctor () [0x00048] in C:\projects\reactiveui\src\ReactiveUI\Android\ControlFetcherMixin.cs:34 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at ReactiveUI.ControlFetcherMixin..cctor () [0x0010c] in C:\projects\reactiveui\src\ReactiveUI\Android\ControlFetcherMixin.cs:45 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: I have converted the Xamarin.Forms project to Xamarin.Android by making Forms PCL to have some shared classes and modifying Xamarin.Android target project. But I still have Xamarin.Forms references in Xamarin.Android project. Will that have any effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual Exception is probably in the InnerException, take special note to this passage in the documentation:

> Because the dictionary is indexed on the lowercase variant of the name, you can't use the same resouce name twice in your layouts with different casings. Android is case-sensitive when generating resource ID's, thus making it impossbile to map this to a single resource ID for use with WireUpControls.

You're probably using multiple resource names that are similar but only differ in casing.